# Can't seem to input any integer values when running the app? It just shows result "grade c"

Tags: java, eclipse

The salary scheme for a company is given as follows:

> Salary range for grade A: $700 - $899
>
> Salary range for grade B: $600 - $799
>
> Salary range for grade C: $500 - $649

A person whose salary is between $600 and $649 is in grade C if his merit points are below 10, otherwise he is in grade B. A person whose salary is between $700 and $799 is in grade B if his merit points are below 20, otherwise, he is in grade A. Write a program to read in a person’s salary and his merit points, and displays his grade.

```
package trydontquit1;
import java.util.*;
 
public class tryagain { 
    public int salary;  
    public int merits;

    public class employee {
        employee (int inputsalary, int inputmerits){
            salary = inputsalary;
            merits = inputmerits;
        }       

        //grade the input in regard to salary and merits point
        void grade() { 
            int c = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
            c = salary - 600;
            b = salary - 700;
            a = salary - 800;
            if (c <= 49 && merits < 10)
                System.out.println("Grade = C");
            else if (b <= 99 && merits < 20)
                System.out.println("Grade = B");
            else if (b > 99)
                System.out.println("Grade = A");
        }
    }
    //to instantiate an object and to grade employee
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int x=0, y=0;       
        System.out.println("Grading of employee");  
        tryagain tryagain = new tryagain();
        employee sc = tryagain.new employee(x,y);
        System.out.println("Please enter salary\n");
        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter merits\n");
        Scanner j = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.grade();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try printing the values inside `grade()` & see if they are what you are expecting

Comment: You don't actually get any input from the scanner(s) and you create the employee with values of 0 and 0 which resutls in the first conditional always executing.

Comment: thanks so much for improving the layout of my question, appreciate, Flakes and Pete.I noticed the flow was not correct but just can't seem to get it right. Thanks so much for your time and efforts Andy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are not reading the inputs. You need to change the flow of the code inside `main` method. please check below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    System.out.println("Grading of employee");
    tryagain tryagain = new tryagain();
    Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter salary\n");
    x = i.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter merits\n");
    y = i.nextInt();
    employee sc = tryagain.new employee(x, y);
    sc.grade();
}
```

Comment: thanks so so so much, i have followed your flow, i got it now and definitely understand a bit better before I post the question....once again, thanks a lot Anuradha.

Answer (score 0):

See the flow

```
int x=0, y=0;       

new employee(x,y);

employee (int inputsalary, int inputmerits){
        salary = inputsalary;
        merits = inputmerits;
 }  

c = salary - 600;
```

salary is always 0

Comment: thanks for the comments, i have reworked on the flow, appreciate your time, efforts and guidance.